# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError Could not initialize class org.bytedeco.javacpp.avutil

Tags: java, opencv, javacv

I have a java application that uses `bytedeco/javacv` library.

but when I run the application, I am getting the following exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.bytedeco.javacpp.avutil
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:386)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:354)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.avformat$AVFormatContext.<clinit>(avformat.java:2719)
    at org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber.startUnsafe(FFmpegFrameGrabber.java:391)
    at org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber.start(FFmpegFrameGrabber.java:385)
    at com.diyoron.ai.examples.VideoFrameProccessor.main(VideoFrameProccessor.java:38)
Error getting static method ID of org/bytedeco/javacpp/Loader/putMemberOffset
```

The code is as following,

```
  String videoPath = video.getAbsolutePath();
  FFmpegFrameGrabber grabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(videoPath);
  grabber.start();
```

According to this following statement in the README.MD

> Additionally, we need to either set the javacpp.platform system
>   property (via the -D command line option) to something like
>   android-arm, or set the javacpp.platform.dependencies one to true to
>   get all the binaries for Android, Linux, Mac OS X, and Windows. On
>   build systems where this does not work, we need to add the
>   platform-specific artifacts manually. For examples with Gradle and
>   sbt, please refer to the README.md file of the JavaCPP Presets.
>   Another option available for Scala users is sbt-javacv.

~ Reference [GitHub](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv).

I added argument -Djavacpp.platform.dependencies="true", But still I am getting the exception. I am not sure what is causing this issue, I have very less experience in working with c++ wrappers.

**PS:** I have not installed any c++ dependencies/libraries or open-cv in my machine. 
 And all the solutions are related to Android and I haven't had much luck following those in my java related application.

Comment: How C++ is coming into picture?

Comment: I am assuming that, javacv is a wrapper for opencv

Comment: Even then C++ language has no role to play for this question.

Comment: Do you have any idea on the issue?

Comment: I am sorry. I am not a Java guy. Note that C++ program gets compiled, and don't need any "C++ virtual machine" kind of thing. Let some Java expert solve your problem! :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the following dependencies resolved the issue.

```
        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bytedeco/javacv -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
            <artifactId>javacv</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bytedeco/javacpp -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
            <artifactId>javacpp</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencv</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0-1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
            <artifactId>ffmpeg</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2-1.2</version>
        </dependency>
```